# Apache POI NoSuchFieldError on setcellformula

Tags: apache, exception, apache-poi

I have an environment where apache poi 3.7 is deployed and getting  following error on server

Exception occurred: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: instance
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1431)
.
.
.

when I try code with main it works fine

here is line where exception occurs

sumcell.setCellFormula("(H"+frow+"*I"+frow+")+(K"+frow+"*L"+frow+")+M"+frow+"+N"+frow);
I try using SUM function but error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). You have two different copies of Apache POI on your classpath, which doesn't work. You need to ensure you only have one copy, which I'd suggest be POI 3.9 as it has lots of bug fixes since 3.7.

I'd strongly suggest you [read through the POI FAQ Entry on NoSuchFieldError](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) and follow the instructions there to track down and remove the duplicate older jar.

Comment: Gagravarr i can't shift to poi 3.9 because this may required testing of the modules (a lot) on production server, i am sure there is only one poi lib on server

Comment: Based on the error you have got, you have multiple copies. Try following the FAQ instructions to find the other one(s)

Comment: Gagravarr I search there is only 1 old jar on server, poi 3.0, I added both the libs in eclipse class path but it is not giving me that error (NoSuchFieldError) with main method in eclipse

Comment: See, you do have an old POI jar! You need to remove that, so that you only have the jars from the version you are using